# How to make a CSS file valid?

Tags: css, w3c-validation

I have a CSS file that uses CSS3 properties (`opacity` and `-moz-*` and `-webkit-*` ones). Of course, it [doesn't validate as CSS 2.1](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fkstatida.ru%2Fpublic%2Fcss.css). Not a big deal, but nevertheless is it possible to make it valid CSS 2.1?

Comment: It's unclear what you're actually asking, because you include the answer to your _stated_ question in the sentence before you ask said question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not without not using those selectors, no.

Answer (score 1):

[Illegal values or unknown properties are being ignored.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS/syndata.html#parsing-errors) So unless you have a syntax error, you can use those values/properties.

Or do you want to have a valid CSS 2.1 stylesheet just to put a badge on your website?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to validate an invalid CSS.

A CSS with not standard selectors is not valid.

Comment: Validating is the process of testing the validity. And *valid* and *invalid* are the results you get when you validate something.

Comment: Since we know the requirements for a document to be accepted as valid, and since we know one of the requirements in not fulfilled, we can predict the result of the validation process in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use all CSS3 properties in another css sheet, and validate that without CSS3 :)